# Importing Maven project is changing src/test/resource structure

Tags: eclipse, maven

Importing Maven Project is splitting src/test/resource folder

Originally, there are multiple packages under that project structure, if I import the maven project into eclipse as existing maven project,

the project is split into
1) src/test/resource/properties 
2) src/test /resource

Please see the before and after screen shot [Original Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDFIt.png)
[Project Structure after import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmpk9.png)

I have bunch of packages on src/test/resources. If I import project into eclipse as an existing Maven project, the src/test/resources folder gets split into 2 structure, not sure why this is happening enter image description here

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the log4j properties in pom.xml was influencing the structure,

removed the following the pom.xml and updated the maven project, and the project structured went to the original state incase anyone in the future runs into this issue--

```
<testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources/properties</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>log4j.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
```